# JavaScript obfuscation and minification in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: firebase, bitbucket, obfuscation, minify, bitbucket-pipelines

I know my code is not worth stealing, but it is worth a "penny" every time someone is downloading it - so how can I make it smaller (must have)/less readable (nice to have) outside of doing it by my own and pushing it to deployable branch?

My current production pipeline looks like that:

```
pipelines:
   branches:
      master:
      - step:
         deployment: production
         caches:
         - node
         script:
         - npm install -g firebase-tools
         - firebase deploy --token=TOKEN --project PROJECT --non-interactive
```

What I have is:

- Firebase hosting
- simple website HTML + CSS + JS

The perfect solution for me would:

- Leave the master branch unchanged
- Perform the minification (and potentially obfuscation) of the code
- Deploy it to firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the solution I have decided to go with:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        deployment: production 
        # trigger: manual  # Uncomment to make this a manual deployment.
        caches:
          - node

    script: 
      - npm install uglify-es -g
      - uglifyjs ./public/scripts/NAME.js -c -m -o ./public/scripts/NAME.js 
      - uglifyjs ./public/scripts/NAME2.js -c -m -o ./public/scripts/NAME2.js 
      - pipe: atlassian/firebase-deploy:0.3.1
        variables:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: 'TOKEN'
          PROJECT_ID: 'PROJECT'
```

It is still WIP, but it works as requested. The files are minified.

The reasoning for the uglify-es - it is the version that supports the ES6 coding guidelines.